# "Type or namespace 'Modules' does not exist in the namespace 'Sdl.Web'" when building DXA 1.7

Tags: dxa, web8.5

I've followed [my own procedure](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/using-and-debugging-dxa-with-web-8-5-on-amazon) (oh, the irony) to setup a new DXA 1.7-based solution with Web 8.5 and when I try building the web application I get the following three errors in Visual Studio (2017):

- Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Modules' does not exist in the namespace 'Sdl.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) c:\Users\Nuno\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\temp\ddc1d5e4\80aaee8a\App_Web_gkb3n4a4.0.cs
- Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Teaser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\Users\Nuno\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\temp\ddc1d5e4\80aaee8a\App_Web_gkb3n4a4.0.cs
- Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Location' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\Users\Nuno\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\temp\ddc1d5e4\80aaee8a\App_Web_gkb3n4a4.1.cs

Any clue? I've tried cleaning up, deleting the temp folder, etc.

Comment: Nuno, did you add the core module to your installation ? In the latest versions of DXA, the core module should be downloaded and installed separately from the main dxa web app.

Comment: Yes, I did - I documented that in my procedure :)

Comment: i noticed that after i put the comment in.
i did recently have some very weird similar behaviour in visual studio as well (not with dxa though), and it all went away when i configured visual studio to use standard IIS instead of the built in IIS express. Wonder if that helped. Also, did you already close and restart visual studio ?

Comment: Could it be related to the 'bitness' of Web Projects in Visual Studio? Check Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Web Projects: Use 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects

Comment: Set to "Any CPU" :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks all for your efforts.

I am an idiot that can't follow his own installation procedure.

In the blog post I mention this:

1. Open powershell, and change current folder to [DXA Root]\modules\core
2. Run ‘web-install.ps1 -distDestination “c:\Dev\Dxa\Site”‘

I had forgotten to include "\Site" in this path, and instead added the Areas folder from "C:\Dev\Dxa" instead of "C:\Dev\Dxa\Site". Fixing this solved my problem, sorry for wasting everyone's time...

Answer (score 2):

I would make sure warnings are also visible to you, in addition to the errors.

Assuming your references are correct, it is likely failing to load those assemblies for some reason and only listing that as a warning - which may not be included in the filter in your IDE. For instance, I've seen this when referencing assemblies compiled for a newer version of .NET than what my project targeted.

If you can see the warnings, you'll likely find the real cause of the issue.

Comment: Thanks Peter - Visual Studio reports 0 warnings, only these 3 errors. The DXA and Tridion libraries all have a target runtime of v4.0.30319, and the project is set to use .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: The weirdest thing is that the project actually runs if I press F5... F6 results in a build failure. I'll get back to this later today.